# Navigation bar color has slightly different color in different devices in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, uinavigationbar, ipod-touch

I am designing an iOS app and my app's navigation bar appears slightly different on different devices. Here are two screenshots demonstrating the issue:

[image]
[image]

As these are taken directly from screenshots (not camera-shots), we are eliminating the issue of some devices having slightly different color rendering in hardware level. All devices have the same and the latest version of iOS (7.1.2). In the above screenshots, one is taken from an iPod and one is taken from an iPhone 5, however, other iPhone 5 are also rendering the colors like the iPod. More interestingly, I've taken the exact colors RGB values in Photoshop (and I use it by setting `UIColor` values in `setTintColor:` from the Photoshop's eyedropper RGB values), and Photoshop renders the like the latter screenshot. To sum it up: Photoshop and one single device renders slightly darker (our intended color) (second screenshot), all the other devices (mix of iPods and iPhones) render slightly lighter (unintended, first screenshot). They all run on iOS 7.1.2.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you notice same difference when you use built in apps? (or may be wallpapers). If display is biased I think there is no way to manage display color profile.

Comment: I would guess a slight change in color would always be there if you compare retina and non-retina devices display

Comment: @Geet As I've mentioned in the post, all devices are retina devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many weeks, we, by coincidence, found out that my friend had his Increase contrast option On on his iPhone's Accesibility settings. He turned it off and it became normal.